# Azure.NotificationHub on Android 6

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to setup Azure NotificationHub with Xamarin up on Android 6, but when I try to install it, it says

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

How can I set it up with Android 6?

Comment: Are you running in Marshmallow ? Its 6.0 Check the version history ..   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add it to a Marshmallow project

Comment: Probably Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager might have a version which supports Marshmallow... Not sure just a vild guess.!

Comment: I tried with the required version and all versions above

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36633694/182371) help?

Comment: No, as I have to send notifications from devices too. Or do I have to this through the server?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Xamarin does not support Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager. 
I tried on my local and get the the same error message as yours. If you want to use Azure notification hub in Xamarin Android. I would recommend you get started with [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/).

Comment: But that is only for retrieval